# How can I use the Report folder name as a parameter to chose the appropriate dataset?

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2016

I am using MS Reporting Services at a school board.  I have a single report that is stored on the SSRS web server and then two linked reports are created to it so it exists in two different folders that have different security access.  One is for Elementary schools and the other for Secondary schools.  Currently the dataset to choose which school to run the report for includes both types of schools.

I have been asked to change the dataset to select only elementary schools if running the linked report from the Elementary folder and only secondary schools if running the linked report from the Secondary folder.  This way it streamlines the options for the user.

I will create separate datasets for Elem and Sec schools and want to pull from the appropriate one.

**How can I use the name of the report folder (or report URL)** that the user is running the linked report from **to be a parameter** in choosing which dataset of schools I want to see in the school name dropdown parameter?

This way the user doesn't have to say they want the elementary school list.  It will already know that since they are coming from the elementary folder.  I wanted to avoid using a School Level parameter too just to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to check the executing folder (I've not looked into if it's possible or not yet). Why not just make the "school type" parameter hidden and set a default value in each of your linked reports. The parameter defaults are stored against the linked copy, not the original one.

You can access the linked reports parameters via the Web Portal on the reports context menu (click the 3 dots and choose 'manage').

Then within your report you can filter the dataset based on this parameter as normal.

Comment: I was thinking to use the Globals!ReportServerUrl as a hidden parameter's default value.

Comment: As Alan mentioned, when using linked reports on different folders, hidden parameters seems the best way to do it.